# How to update a field which is of type array by using script in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I had a field named 'tags' in my documents, which is of type array, how can I do this:

```
If a tag is in the field 'tags', then do nothing; else add the tag to 'tags'.
```

Forgive me that I have no idea with groovy, but I've tried this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/file/company/13862/_update?pretty -d '{script:{inline:"ctx._source.tags.contains(tag) ? ctx.op=\"noop\" : ctx._source.tags += tag", params: {tag: 3}}}'
```

But it turns out the error:

> "Failed to compile inline script [ctx._source.tags.contains(tag) ? ctx.op=\"noop\" : ctx._source.tags += tag] using lang [groovy]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "if(ctx._source.tags.contains(tag)){ ctx.op = \"none\"} else{ ctx._source.tags += tag }",
    "params": {
      "tag": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it.